# Is there a built in way to keep Angular dialog box higher than center?

Tags: css, angular

I am generating a dialog box on a private Angular 6 app and based on how the designer wants, it sits too low unless of course my screen height is reduced, it's responsive and creates a cdk-overlay that has

```
style="justify-content: center; align-items: center;"
```

The documentation for angular 6 dialog here: https://v6.material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview

Unfortunately I don't see a config option or parameters that can set a max distance from the top, for example I never want the box further than say 200px from top. Any thought's or ideas on accomplishing this? Here is the general code driving all of this:

.ts code:

```
this.blahDialog.open(this.dialogTemplate, 'test', {
                    maxWidth: '300px',
                    data: {announceHeader: this.announceHeader, announceTitle: this.announceTitle, announceBody: this.announceBody}
                });
                this.announce = false;
```

pre html template:

```
<ng-template #dialogTemplate>
  <div class="customer-notification">
    <div class="customer-notification-header">
    <p><img src="../../../images/blah.svg" alt="Blah"> {{ announceHeader }}</p>
    </div>
    <div class="customer-notification-body">
          <h3 mat-dialog-title class="customer-notification-title">{{ announceTitle }}</h3>
          <p mat-dialog-content class="customer-notification-content">{{ announceBody }}</p>
      <div class="spacer-12"></div>
      <div mat-dialog-actions class="dialog-buttons" layout="row">
        <button ng-disabled="false" mat-raised-button id="got-it" class="outline-btn-prtl" color="primary" (click)="blahDialog.close('test', true)">GOT IT</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
```

The generated code is:

```
<div class="cdk-global-overlay-wrapper" dir="ltr" style="justify-content: center; align-items: center;"><div id="cdk-overlay-2" class="cdk-overlay-pane" style="max-width: 300px; pointer-events: auto; position: static;"><div tabindex="0" class="cdk-visually-hidden cdk-focus-trap-anchor"></div><mat-dialog-container aria-modal="true" class="mat-dialog-container ng-tns-c40-45 ng-trigger ng-trigger-slideDialog ng-star-inserted" tabindex="-1" id="mat-dialog-0" role="dialog" style="transform:none;opacity:1;0:transform;1:opacity;opacity:1;transform:none;webkit-opacity:1;webkit-transform:none;"><!----><div _ngcontent-c37="" class="customer-notification ng-star-inserted" style=""><div _ngcontent-c37="" class="customer-notification-header"><p _ngcontent-c37=""><img _ngcontent-c37="" alt="AbacusNext" src="./blah"> Announcement</p></div><div _ngcontent-c37="" class="customer-notification-body"><h3 _ngcontent-c37="" class="customer-notification-title" mat-dialog-title="">24/7 Support Tier</h3><p _ngcontent-c37="" class="customer-notification-content" mat-dialog-content="">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.</p><div _ngcontent-c37="" class="spacer-12"></div><div _ngcontent-c37="" class="dialog-buttons" layout="row" mat-dialog-actions=""><button _ngcontent-c37="" class="outline-btn-prtl mat-raised-button mat-primary" color="primary" id="got-it" mat-raised-button="" ng-disabled="false"><span class="mat-button-wrapper">GOT IT</span><div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div><div class="mat-button-focus-overlay"></div></button></div></div></div></mat-dialog-container><div tabindex="0" class="cdk-visually-hidden cdk-focus-trap-anchor"></div></div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the dialog-config.d.ts accepts an object with top, bottom, left or right and the position. So in my request for help, it looks like this is all I needed to add:

```
position: {top: '200px'}
```

or

```
this.blahDialog.open(this.dialogTemplate, 'test', {
                    maxWidth: '300px',
                    position: {top: '200px'},
                    data: {announceHeader: this.announceHeader, announceTitle: this.announceTitle, announceBody: this.announceBody}
                });
                this.announce = false;
```

Simple enough but instead of deleting someone else might run into the same problem.

Comment: no one has came up with a better solution after some time so accepting as answer.